# PhantomJS / Javascript: download web page and write to text file

Tags: phantomjs

Below code is download web page it work fine but i want to save i put code for write text file honestly i have no idea how i can do this to save file

```
var url = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open(url, function(status) {
    if (status === 'success') {
        var html = page.evaluate(function() {
        return document.documentElement.outerHTML;
        });
        console.log(html);
    }
var fs = require('fs');
   try {
    fs.write("C:\phantomjs\\qhxpZ.txt", "Message to be written to the file", 'w');
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }   
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: Also, make sure that the path is correct. You probably want to have `C:\\phantomjs\\qhxpZ.txt` (with both \ doubled.)

Answer (score 2):

So, for completeness, the solution to the issue at hand should look something like:

```
var url = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
var fs = require('fs');
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open(url, function(status) {
    if (status === 'success') {
        var html = page.evaluate(function() {
            return document.documentElement.outerHTML;
        });
        try {
            fs.write("C:\\phantomjs\\qhxpZ.txt", html, 'w');
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: page.content does not contain page changes by DHTML JavaScript; outerHtml does.

Comment: (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { var page = require('webpage').create(),

Answer (score 0):

just replace "Message to be written to the file" with html and file will be saved.

```
fs.write("C:\phantomjs\\qhxpZ.txt", "Message to be written to the file", 'w');
```